# how to get numeric values form sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

My problem is I have a table in which offers are stored and I want to display only those records who have 50% (the substring '50%' in them).

This is my table Schema:
[image]
An Example record would be:

> FLAT 50% Off on Essel world entry tickets and more.
>   FLAT 50% Off on Rs
>   2495 & above. U.S polo - Upto 50% off

How would I go about composing an SQL query to select these? The column name of the field is called `coupon_name`

Comment: use wildcard character `%`

Comment: Is every string formatted the same? Will the % always be two digits?

Comment: what are the tables and column structure? and query you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Like will do..

```
 select * from table
    where coupon_name like '%50[%]%'
```

This will give all records  like below one having 250,this can be valid since percentage can't be greater than 100

```
sakfjfjk50%sfjbsadjkfbjksdf
sakfjfjk250%sfjbsadjkfbjksdf
```

Comment: shouldn't it would like `%50\%%` ?

Comment: its work fine but i need only records which have only 50%

Answer (score 0):

I you need records containing '50%' you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE coupon_name LIKE '%50[%]%'
```

Or use `ESCAPE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE coupon_name LIKE '%50\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE coupon_name LIKE '%50|%%' ESCAPE '|'
```

The third one should work in MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELECT * FROM Vcom WHERE coupon_title LIKE '%50\%%' LIMIT 0 , 30' at line 1

Comment: SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE coupon_name LIKE '%50[%]%' returns zero rows

Comment: @pawal still zero rows 

SELECT *
FROM Vcom
WHERE coupon_title LIKE '%50|%%'